# Setting filename for saving buffer

Tags: debugging

I am using the following function `workbench`.  How may I resolve the error

```
if: Wrong type argument: sequencep, 1
```

when calling `M-x workbench`?

With backtrace I get

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument sequencep 1)
  concat("~/wb/" "2022-06-29-T13:51:06--" "Arktika" "-" 1 ".org")
  (if name (concat workbench-dtrek (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S--") workbench-prefix "-" name ".org") (concat workbench-dtrek (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S--") workbench-prefix ".org"))
  (let* ((wbfrmt (concat "*" workbench-prefix "%s%s*")) (buffer (if name (format wbfrmt "-" name) (format wbfrmt "" ""))) (file-name (if name (concat workbench-dtrek (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S--") workbench-prefix "-" name ".org") (concat workbench-dtrek (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S--") workbench-prefix ".org")))) (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer buffer)) (setq buffer-file-name file-name) (if current-prefix-arg (let* ((mode (completing-read " Langmode [progr,markup]: " (map-keys workbench-modes) nil t nil 'workbench-histr))) (funcall (intern mode))) (funcall (intern (or mode "org-mode")))) buffer-file-name)
  workbench(1)
  funcall-interactively(workbench 1)
  call-interactively(workbench record nil)
  command-execute(workbench record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "workbench" "ark")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "workbench" "ark")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Looks as the problem relates to the condition `(if name`

```
(defvar workbench-prefix "Arktika")

(defvar workbench-dtrek "~/wb/")

(defvar workbench-histr nil)

(defvar workbench-modes
  '( ("emacs-lisp-mode" . "el")
     ("lisp-mode" . "lisp")
     ("org-mode" . "org")
     ("f90-mode" . "f90")
     ("c-mode" . "c")
     ("c++-mode" . "cpp")
     ("sh-script" . "sh") ))

(defun workbench (&optional name mode)
  "Generate new temporary buffer."
  (interactive "p")

  (let* ( (wbfrmt
             (concat "*" workbench-prefix "%s%s*"))
          (buffer
             (if name (format wbfrmt "-" name) (format wbfrmt "" "")))
          (file-name
             (if name
                 (concat workbench-dtrek
                         (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S--")
                          workbench-prefix "-" name ".org")
               (concat workbench-dtrek
                       (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S--")
                       workbench-prefix ".org"))) )

    (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer buffer))
    (setq buffer-file-name file-name)

    (if current-prefix-arg
        (let* ( (mode (completing-read " Langmode [progr,markup]: "
                        (map-keys workbench-modes) nil t nil
                        'workbench-histr)) )
          (funcall (intern mode)))

      (funcall (intern (or mode "org-mode"))))

    buffer-file-name))
```

Comment: `M-x set-variable debug-on-error t` Show the backtrace, if it doesn't make clear to you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs is telling you everything you need to know:

- `(wrong-type-argument sequencep 1)`: emacs is telling you that it got the number `1` when it was expecting a sequence (something like a list or string)
- `concat("~/wb/" "2022-06-29-T13:51:06--" "Arktika" "-" 1 ".org")` shows what was executing when that happened and the error is clear: you are trying to concatenate a raw number as though it was a string.

Now look at the code and see `1` must be the value of the argument `name`. This is an artifact of your `interactive` form.  Is this really what you want?  If so, replace `name` by `(number-to-string name)`.

Comment: No, I do not wish to have a `1`.  I was expecting to get a `nil`o r an empty value when no argument is passed, using `(if name` to either use `name` in the filename or skip it.

Comment: It is because (interactive "p") uses the numeric prefix argument.

Comment: What should I use to solve this problem, and be able to get the name included in file-name?

Comment: Don't try and harvest the `name` arg with `interactive`: just do a `read-string` similar to what you do with the `mode` arg.  More general advice: it is way more fun to experiment and try things out in the scratch buffer than ask this forum all the time.

Comment: It is fun but am finding interactive features hard.